# Problem: Find a basis for the kernel of $L(A) = A - A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem, and I have a solution, but I am not sure if it is correct. If you could spot potential confusions, I would be grateful.

**Problem:** Let $M_{2,2}$ be the vector space of 2×2 real matrices. Let L be the linear operator on $M_{2,2}$ given by

\begin{equation}
L(A)=A-A^T.
\end{equation}

Find a basis for ker(L).

**Solution:** Since $L(A)=A-A^T$, we're looking for vectors that send $L(A)=A-A^T$ to $0$. This is equivalent to the condition

\begin{equation}
A=A^T.
\end{equation}

But this is just a definition of symmetric matrices. Define a 2x2 symmetric matrix $S$ as

\begin{equation}
S=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

To find the kernel of L, take the span of $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} b \\ a \end{bmatrix}$. Hence, a basis for $\mathrm{Ker(L)}$ is

$$\textrm{Ker(L)}=\biggl\{\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} b \\ a \end{bmatrix}\biggr\}.$$

Comment: The kernel of $L$ is the set of symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices. It cannot be spanned by $2 \times 1$ matrices.

Comment: @Bosco Also, not every symmetric matrix has the form $\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}$. More generally, $\pmatrix{a&b\\b&c}$ is also symmetric.

Comment: @Bosco Note also that the entries of your basis elements should be numbers, not variables like $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$; which can be expressed as the linear combination:
$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$
So the basis (standard) is $B=\big\{ \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \}$

Answer (score 2):

So you correctly noted that your kernel is the set of $2×2$ symmetric matrices.   But you made a mistake in the definition and didn't get the basis right.

A symmetric $2×2$ matrix is any $\begin {pmatrix}a\quad b\\b\quad c\end{pmatrix}$.

Here's a basis:   $$\{\begin{pmatrix}1\quad 0\\0\quad 0\end {pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0\quad 1\\1\quad 0\end {pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0\quad 0\\0\quad 1\end {pmatrix}\}$$.

Comment: Yes, but why? I think that would be more useful to OP.

Comment: If I belabor the obvious can I get a gold bell?  @azif00

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It is correct. The person writing the question presented a good-faith attempt to solve it also. +1